# Getting mono related Exception while generating build when upgraded to El-capitan

Tags: build, mono, osx-elcapitan, nstask

Here is the code by which i am trying to generate build.

```
 NSTask *task=[[NSTask alloc]init];

 NSArray *arguments1 =  @[@"-v",@"archive",@"--   configuration:AppStore|iPhone",@"/XXX/SimpleTableView.sln"];

[task setArguments:arguments1];

[task setLaunchPath: @"/Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/MacOS/mdtool"];
NSPipe *pipe=[[NSPipe alloc]init];
[task setStandardOutput:pipe];
[task setStandardInput:[NSPipe pipe]];

[task launch];    [task waitUntilExit];
```

but it is giving this error.

Unhandled Exception:
   Nested exception detected.

Original Exception: at (wrapper managed-to-native)     System.RuntimeType.getFullName (System.RuntimeType,bool,bool) 
at System.RuntimeType.ToString () [0x00000] in /private/tmp/source-mono-mac-4.2.0-branch/bockbuild-mono-4.2.0-branch/profiles/mono-mac-xamarin/build-root/mono-4.2.1/mcs/class/corlib/ReferenceSources/RuntimeType.cs:533

It was running fine when it was on os x yosemite.but after upgrading to el capitan it is giving this error.Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

don't see why this is a MCS error that should be reported to this forum? Any evidence? Note that Xamarin is not MCS

Frank

Comment: I don't know if this exception is directly related to mcs file but this code was running fine when it was on yosemite .Now on el-capitan it is giving this exception.i think this exception is related to the configuration of mono framework or related path that has been changed on el capitan.